# How do I create an image and save it for later to draw as texture in XNA?

Tags: c#, image, xna, geometry

In my game I need to draw a circle made of squares the sizes of a game tile (circle is made of squares). I could just draw monochrome square textures in form of a jagged circle each frame, but it consumes a significant amount of resources. What I'd like to do is to draw it somewhere in the memory just once and save to draw each frame after that.

I could simply draw said circle myself and use it as a ready texture, but my circle is not always the same. It has different size throughout the game (and it's not really a circle half of the time, but I've got the algo that says where to draw), so it has to be drawn programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you render the circle to a custom `RenderTarget2D`. You can set a custom render target like this:

```
GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(renderTarget);
```

After rendering your circle to the render target cast it to a `Texture2D` like this:

```
texture = (Texture2D)renderTarget;
```

Read more: http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series3/Render_to_texture.php

Comment: Please note that, in XNA 4.0, a `RenderTarget2D` *is* a `Texture2D` (and you can use it as such) and that casting it doesn't actually *do* anything. Unless you actually *copy* it to a a new `Texture2D` (using a combination of `GetData` and `SetData`) and use that instead, it is possible that your `RenderTarget2D` will be lost (triggering its `ContentLost` event and setting `IsContentLost` to true).