# Separating textures by randomly generated lines

Tags: c#, xna, textures

I have a problem which I can't seem to find a different solution for at the moment that is a bit more efficient to my current idea.

I am making a little game with XNA which will have a randomly generated path to move along, but I don't know how to separate the textures above and below the lines, since the lines are randomly generated. I hope this image can explain the problem:

[image]

So the line(s) are randomly added. My own idea was to create a lot of rectangles with different heights and position them next to each other, but I think that is a little bit inefficient and it also forces me the line to be thick enough such that the rectangle can be a bit wider than only 1-2 pixel, otherwise you might see some "emtpy" spots near the line.

If anything is unclear, please feel free to ask and I will add it to the question, but I think my problem should be clear enough.

Comment: How are you representing lines?

Comment: The lines will be small images (say 10x30 pixels) which will be generated one next to the other rotated at some random angle and put next to each other.

Comment: Do add: the angle of rotation will be probably -0.2 to 0.2 rad and the angular difference between two adjecent line rotations will not be bigger than 0.1 rad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could **replace pixels** you don't need **with transparent** pixels:

```
//extract pixel data from texture
Texture2D topTexture = ...
Color[] topTextureData = new Color[topTexture.Width * topTexture.Height];
topTexture.GetData<Color>(topTextureData);

for(int x = 0; x < topTexture.Width; x++)
{
    //depending on how you represent lines, set transparent all the pixels at and below line
    //basically, for each x dimension, you find where the line is - you have to
    //write the method for getting this y, as I don't know how you represent lines
    int lineY = GetLineYAtThisX(x);

    //all the pixels at (and below) the line are set transparent
    for(int y = lineY; y < topTexture.Height; y++)
    {
        topTextureData[x + y * topTexture.Width] = Color.Transparent;
    }  
}

//save this data into another texture, so you don't ruin the original one.
Texture2D maskedTopTexture = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, topTexture.Width, topTexture.Height);
maskedTopTexture.SetData<Color>(topTextureData);
```

You don't even have to do this for the bottom one, just draw the top one above it.

Comment: Very nice idea, I hope the computer can do it fast enough, to maintain 30 fps

Answer (score 1):

One solution to this problem is creating a masking texture that will obscure the texture outside of chosen area.

[mad skills incoming!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfGke.png)

The black area will not be drawn. Do the opposite for the other texture and you will get what you want.

I'm not sure how to work with spritebatch on that, but the general solution to your problem probably uses masks.

Comment: The problem is, that I would need to create this mask randomly, how exactly can I do that using XNA?

Comment: There is a way to save a rendered texture (or a whole game screen) to a Texture2D. Take a look at [this question's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11943483/1306322)

Comment: But then again I would need to create the black texture which fits underneath the lines. That is the whole problem, or do you have some idea to do it? At the moment it sounds a bit complicated

Comment: You could try using premade small tiles which will be put together in a random pattern and look like they are actually random, but it has certain limitations, and I don't know how you intend to use your texture, so you may be needing a totally different approach. It all depends on how you use it.

Comment: Okay, good point. I will try to think of a way. I will give you +1 for pointing out masks to me, I wasn't aware of them in XNA before.